# what language should i learn for the future

Tags: programming-languages

what language is really gonna be used in the future?

Comment: You should look at related questions on this site to find an answer.

Comment: I would definitely recommend Scala. It changed my life, maybe it'll change yours too. :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pluralistic universe. Ruby Java Python C Objective-C Scala Small-talk F Assembler etc.... everything in its place. Even PHP will continue to exist and even gain in popularity, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Fortran and COBOL.

They were used a lot in the past, and they're used a lot in the present, and unless things change drastically (and I see no reason to believe they will), they're going to be used a lot in the future.